# Restore database made by pgadmin4 in entrypoint docker's container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pgadmin-4

I made backup from my database by `pgadmins4` and stored into my dockerfile location.

Now i create a custom docker image by my docker file:

```
FROM mdillon/postgis:11-alpine
LABEL MAINTAINER groot
ENV LANG en_US.utf8
ENV DBNAME pglocations
ENV USERNAME postgres

COPY init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./pglocations.sql .
```

I built an image and when i want to create container i got this erors:

```
server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
CREATE DATABASE
2019-08-27 06:07:31.790 UTC [43] ERROR:  index "user_device_id" does not exist
2019-08-27 06:07:31.790 UTC [43] STATEMENT:  DROP INDEX public.user_device_id;

2019-08-27 06:07:31.790 UTC [43] ERROR:  index "uid" does not exist
2019-08-27 06:07:31.790 UTC [43] STATEMENT:  DROP INDEX public.uid;

2019-08-27 06:07:31.790 UTC [43] ERROR:  index "timestamp" does not exist
2019-08-27 06:07:31.790 UTC [43] STATEMENT:  DROP INDEX public."timestamp";

2019-08-27 06:07:31.791 UTC [43] ERROR:  index "temp_mileage_location_user_id_idx" does not exist
2019-08-27 06:07:31.791 UTC [43] STATEMENT:  DROP INDEX public.temp_mileage_location_user_id_idx;

2019-08-27 06:07:31.791 UTC [43] ERROR:  index "temp_mileage_location_shape_idx" does not exist
2019-08-27 06:07:31.791 UTC [43] STATEMENT:  DROP INDEX public.temp_mileage_location_shape_idx;

2019-08-27 06:07:31.791 UTC [43] ERROR:  index "temp_mileage_location_device_id_idx" does not exist
2019-08-27 06:07:31.791 UTC [43] STATEMENT:  DROP INDEX public.temp_mileage_location_device_id_idx; 
...
```

In my database i added **postgis** and **uuid.ossp** extension and 2 functions.

By Pgadmin4 i can restore this database.

This my init.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --dbname template1 --username postgres <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE "$DBNAME"
    WITH OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    TEMPLATE template0;
EOSQL

#start postgres database
pg_restore -d "$DBNAME" pglocations.sql -c -U "$USERNAME"
```

This is my container mount palce:

**docker inspect -f '{{json .Mounts }}' pg-docker**

```
[{"Type":"volume","Name":"a0334d571a61c0a17a23ca4be6a191143f39657967c52b3326abf8c011f54861","Source":"/var/lib/docker/volumes/a0334d571a61c0a17a23ca4be6a191143f39657967c52b3326abf8c011f54861/_data","Destination":"/var/lib/postgresql/data","Driver":"local","Mode":"","RW":true,"Propagation":""}]
```

Comment: see https://simkimsia.com/how-to-restore-database-dumps-for-postgres-in-docker-container/

Comment: I changed dockerfile `COPY ./pglocations.sql /var/lib/postgresql/data` but when i create container `docker run  --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123  safapostgis:11.2`  i got `initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".` @LinPy

Comment: remove all your containers, images and volumes first then recreate the container

Comment: Firs i removed container and then removed image finally i create image again `docker build -t safapostgis:11.2 .`  but in creating time in `init.sh` file when container wants restore the database i got error @LinPy

Comment: This is new dockerfile  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gcSkzR8Rd4/ @LinPy

Answer (score 0):

First follow these [Steps](https://simkimsia.com/how-to-restore-database-dumps-for-postgres-in-docker-container/)

second: you should not copy any file in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` in your `Build` stage - change docker file to :

```
FROM mdillon/postgis:11-alpine

LABEL MAINTAINER groot
ENV LANG en_US.utf8
ENV DBNAME pglocations
ENV USERNAME postgres
COPY init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

then start your `container` after **building** the new image:

```
docker run --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123 -v  /path/to/pglocations.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/pglocations.sql safapostgis:11.2
```

Comment: There is noway to put my database into my image to restore automatically when creating container? @LinPy

Comment: See the error you got the folder should be empty to initialize

Comment: Ok but i did copy into `.` location and when creation time read `.` and try to restore it @LinPy

Comment: sorry, i did not get you, what do you mean

Comment: I mean, I want the database to be automatically restored when the container is created @LinPy

Comment: Ok dude, for the reason i made `init.sh` @LinPy